# LST calculation from Landsat 8 and 7 shows really different output

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, landsat-8, landsat-7, land-surface-temperature

I am trying to calculate LST for my region using ArcMap 10.5, but it shows different output and resolution. The first image is Landsat 7 (2012) and the second one is Landsat 8 (2022).

[image: LST calculation using Landsat 7 (date: 2012)]

[image: LST calculation using Landsat 8 (date: 2022)]

[image: built-up areas]

So, logically there is no big high-temperature location difference between both years, it follows the built-up area (the third map with red-grey color depicts land cover, the red one is the built-up area). I hope anyone knows what the core problem is.

Is it from the data source/quality?

I got the data from the USGS website and I choose the smallest cloud cover for both. I use Band 6 VCID 1 and Band 10 for both respectively.

Any suggestion for getting my final LST calculation output for both years (2012 and 2022)?

Comment: Thermal band of Landsat 7 has 60 m resolution whereas that of Landsat 8 has 100 m. This can be the reason. You can resample the bands to similar resolution.

Comment: but it says that the L7 and L8 thermal bands are already resampled to 30 m